# HTML Marquee bounces back when it reaches end when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I use a normal marquee the text goes to the end and doesn't bounce back to the start as soon as it touches the end of the div.

I want to achieve this effect when using jQuery to grab echo'd PHP on another page.

Example:
[image]

Code:
**Index.html**

```
<marquee id="slider" class="panel panel-default" style="width:50%;"></marquee>
<marquee class="panel panel-default" style="width:50%;">Doesn't Bounce Back when reaches the end</marquee>

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function()
{
   $.ajax({url:"/test2", type:"GET", async:true, cache:false, success:function(result)
{
     $("#slider").html(result);
}});

},2500);
</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
echo "Bounces Back when reaches the end";
?>
```

So in the image example above, I want the first marquee to have to same effect as the bottom one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add a containing element inside the marque for our text, the marque will continue to run  smoothly as we are not targeting the marque with new html directly - see - http://jsfiddle.net/Uy6S8/

**MARKUP**

```
<marquee id="slider" class="panel panel-default">
    <span id="sliderText">I am the marquee text</span>
</marquee>
```

**JS**

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#sliderText").html("I am new Marquee Text");
},10000);
```

Comment: *Been that long since used marquee that I have forgotten how it is spelt : )